# Getting rid of non-topological heads in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have the following situation in my repository:

```
A----B----F----G----(long time)----H       <- default branch, H is what I'm working on
      \
       C----D                              <- default branch, long time ago
             \
              E                            <- non-default named branch
```

I'm working in the default branch, the current revision is H, the tip. Sadly in historic times, someone worked on D and then branched this into a named branch, in revision E. (This was actually an SVN import, but that doesn't matter).

Until now, that was not a problem, because D is not a topological head. But nowadays I use buildbot to perform some testing and buildbot complains about multiple heads in the default branch. This is correct, because it uses `hg heads` to determine the default heads.

How can I get rid of D being a head of the default branch? I thought about closing D via `hg commit --close-branch`. But doesn't that create an actual topological head?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer: No**

Illustrated answer

`>hg glog --template "{rev}-{branch}\n"`

```
o  9-German
|
| @  8-default
| |
o |  7-default
| |
o |  6-default
| |
o |  5-default
| |
| o  4-default
| |
| o  3-default
| |
| o  2-default
| |
| o  1-default
|/
o  0-default
```

`>hg heads`

```
changeset:   9:62eaf0f52632
branch:      German

changeset:   8:39b0fec94839

changeset:   7:d98a89a763cf
```

`>hg up 7`

`>hg commit --close-branch -m "Close variation"`

`>hg heads`

```
changeset:   9:62eaf0f52632
branch:      German

changeset:   8:39b0fec94839
```

New topological head **will appear only** in case of creating (non-closed) childs of 10

[image: Repo-Tree]

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is in:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches

Basically closing of a revision exclude that leaf of history from user visible UI (`hg heads` & `hg branches`) but never makes them non-topological heads.

To remove a topological head you strip that history leaf or merge it somewhere (don't forget to include branch closing commit into a merge!).

Keeping topological heads slows remote protocol a lot. Hg hosting companies complained about this forcing customers to merge/strip changes in the past ))